# How do I make a persistent change to Docker's default network subnet (v1.7/)?

Tags: docker

The default subnet used by docker (172.17.0.0/16) conflicts with an internally allocated network leading to routing problems for some hosts on my network.  Searching for instructions on how to reconfigure this subnet, I've found conflicting directions (introduced by newer functionality in recent versions of Docker?) and instructions about how to reconfigure the interface once it's already up, but nothing which describes how to make the change persistent and activated when the service starts.

I am running Docker on CentOS 6.8, which limits me to the 1.7 version.  Some of the solutions I've found work through the "docker network" command, which does not appear to be available at this version.

How do I make a persistent change to the default docker subnet using docker 1.7 on CentOS 6.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/

In summary, the docker daemon accepts a "--bip=CIDR" (bip == "Bridge IP"?) option, which allows a subnet to be specified.  In RHEL/CentOS, this option should be placed in the "other_args" variable in /etc/sysconfig/docker.

My /etc/sysconfig/docker file contains the line:

other_args="--bip=192.168.124.0/24"